# Bidirectional communication from Camel to Vertx socket Server

Tags: apache-camel, netty, vert.x

I am trying to use Camel NettyComponent to communicate with a SocketServer written in Vert.x.

This is my server code:

```
public class NettyExampleServer {

    public final Vertx vertx;

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NettyExampleServer.class);

    public static int LISTENING_PORT = 15692;

    public NettyExampleServer(Vertx vertx) {
        this.vertx = vertx;
    }

    private NetServer netServer;

    private List<String> remoteAddresses = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
    private final AtomicInteger disconnections = new AtomicInteger();

    public int getDisconnections(){
        return disconnections.get();
    }

    public List<String> getRemoteAddresses(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(remoteAddresses);
    }

    public void run(){
        netServer = vertx.createNetServer();
        netServer.connectHandler(new Handler<NetSocket>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final NetSocket socket) {
                remoteAddresses.add(socket.remoteAddress().toString());
                socket.closeHandler(new Handler<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Void event) {
                        disconnections.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                });
                socket.dataHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Buffer event) {
                        logger.info("I received {}",event);
                        socket.write("I am answering");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        netServer.listen(LISTENING_PORT);



    }

    public void stop(){
        netServer.close();
    }
}
```

I tried to build a Route like the following:

```
public class NettyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    public static final String PRODUCER_BUS_NAME = "producerBus";
    public static final String CONSUMER_BUS_NAME = "receiverBus";

    private Processor processor = new Processor(){
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            exchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("vertx:" + PRODUCER_BUS_NAME).process(processor).to("netty:tcp://localhost:"+ NettyExampleServer.LISTENING_PORT + "?textline=true&lazyChannelCreation=true&option.child.keepAlive=true").to("vertx:"+CONSUMER_BUS_NAME);

    }
}
```

My tests shows that:

- If I eliminate the processor on the route, the delivery succeed but there is no answer by the server
- If I keep the processor, the data is delivered to the server but an exception raise because no data is received.

I have created a small project here:  https://github.com/edmondo1984/netty-camel-vertx . How do I use Camel Netty Component to create a bidirectional route ?

Comment: Not sure if this will help but a Netty routes are a IN/OUT message exchange pattern i.e request, reply. The server cannot send a message back without getting a request first. I will have a look at the project when I get a chance.

Comment: The server receive the request and writes back on the socket but the client doesn't receive anything

Comment: Cool will check the code a little when I have a moment. Stuck in reverse engineering a legacy application hell at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate Vertx and Camel the best tool is to use one of this:

- [Camel Vertex endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/vertx.html)
- [Vertex Camel connector](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-camel-bridge/java/)

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/camel-bridge-examples)

If you could or have another requeriments it is possible also to use a common connector like Netty on the both sides.